# What's the meaning of "doing fifty five in a fifty four" in "99 problems" by Jay-Z

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, lyrics

In the song "99 Problems" by Jay-Z the performer is rapping about getting pulled over by the police. The purported reason for being pulled over is given by the police officer as *"doing fifty five in a fifty four"*.

My current interpretation is that the officer is talking about a speeding violation, and that Jay-Z was doing 55 miles per hour (mph) in a zone where the maximum speed limit is 54 mph, but that does not really make sense as [*"speed limits are typically posted in increments of five miles per hour (mph)"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_the_United_States).

Was the officer just making up some bogus offence, or is there a deeper meaning to the phrase *"doing fifty five in a fifty four"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd think this is just a matter of lyrical freedom, keeping rhyme intact whilst emphasising the fact that one mph transgression is only just a reason to pull him over.

See also this close reading from a lawyer's perspective from the article [Jay-Z’s 99 Problems, Verse 2: A Close Reading with Fourth Amendment Guidance for Cops and Perps](http://www.slu.edu/Documents/law/Law%20Journal/Archives/LJ56-2_Mason_Article.pdf):

> *You was doing fifty-five in a fifty-four . . .*
>     All drivers—not just those smuggling drugs—have reason to complain about what they see as arbitrary speed enforcement.  Drive down a highway with a marked limit of sixty-five, and you’ll see that virtually every car is speeding.  The cultural norm we learn as drivers is that anything within ten miles per hour of the posted limit is okay. [49]
>     But as a matter of law—which is what matters for the suppression 
>   issue—if you’re even one mile per hour over, that’s sufficient to pull you over, write you a ticket, and, if the officer chooses, to arrest you. [50]
>     Neither arbitrariness nor pretextual motive is relevant to the validity of the stop if it is based on probable cause that you were in fact violating the traffic law. [51]
>     **Jay-Z explains the line as “another way of saying that we’re being pulled over for no good reason.”** [52] As numerous commentators have observed, the number and scope of traffic regulations is so extensive that the police can in practice find a perfectly legitimate traffic-law basis for stopping any car they choose, just by following it for a few blocks. [53]

Comment: That seems to be it. I just accidently googled the article [Jay-Z’S 99 Problems, Verse 2: A Close Reading with Fourth Amendment Guidance for Cops and Perps](http://www.slu.edu/Documents/law/Law%20Journal/Archives/LJ56-2_Mason_Article.pdf). I took the liberty to edit the relevant passage into your answer. That passage references the book *Decoded*, which contains Jay-Z's explanations of his lyrics, so it seems definitive.

Comment: I must admit, that is quite the amazing paper you linked to there...

Comment: And I've Approved it.